# Can JoomlaDay events offer "Not a Robot" badges to JSE users?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags, interesting-tags

I want to do something cool at [JoomlaDay Australia 2019 in Brisbane](https://joomladay.org.au/)!

StackOverflow has this tag: [not-a-robot](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/not-a-robot)  Can JSE have it too?

Resources:

- https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/6381/not-a-robot
- https://stackoverflow.com/badges/get/events

I think it would be highly effective in increasing JSE awareness and user registrations to offer this badge to attendees (not just in Brisbane, but world-wide for all major Joomla User Group events).

Is this something that moderators can facilitate?  I don't know if we have any "employees" in Oceania that can attend (or if that is entirely necessary to credibly disseminate these badged).

As a Stack Exchange fanatic, I can virtually guarantee that there will be some sort of presentation / workshop dedicated to explaining the sheer awesomeness of JSE and how to best interact with it. It is my opinion that **every major Joomla event *should be* making mention of JSE in some capacity**. This community may or may not ever be promoted above Beta status, but I reckon we should take all available opportunities to give it a good crack and ramp things up.

And before I go, let me just include a direct link to our [Joomla Day Australia 2019 pre-event survey](https://joomladay.org.au/program/have-your-say). We are trying to reach all Joomla users in Oceania (specifically: site owners, content managers, developers, agencies, and even companies that do business with Joomla users). Please complete the 5 minute survey and tell your colleagues, clients, and friends to do the same.  We are randomly awarding 1 Buy-One-Get-One coupon (worth $175AUD) for our JoomlaDay on the 15th of each month leading up to the event (9 draws in total; first on Nov 15 and last on Jul 15).  Obviously, the earlier you complete the survey, the more times you go into the lottery!

Let's grow Joomla in every way conceivable!

Please upvote if you like this idea.